# ^ after data type in Visual C++

Tags: c++, syntax, c++-cli

What does `^` mean near the c++ data type?

[image]

This seems to only work in visual studio C++ and is clearly **not** a *standard C++ syntax*, so what does it do here?
I am familiar with pointer `*` and reference `&`, but to see `^` after the data type, I have no clue.

Comment: it's a Microsoft CLI language extension.

Comment: @Bathsheba So it is supposed to be called managed pointer?, sorry about that. I am not familiar with it, and this is my first time using visual c++ form application, anyway I am familiar that this is not a standard c++ syntax :)

Comment: Personally I wouldn't waste my time with it. This "managed C++" thing is a disaster. If you want to build GUIs in C++, then use Qt and *standard* C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++/CLI and C++/CX, `^` is the [Handle to Object Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-170):

> The *handle declarator* (`^`, pronounced "hat"), modifies the type specifier to mean that the declared object should be automatically deleted when the system determines that the object is no longer accessible.
>
> ...
>
> Because native C++ pointers (`*`) and references (`&`) are not managed references, the garbage collector cannot automatically update the addresses they point to. To solve this problem, use the handle declarator to specify a variable that the garbage collector is aware of and can update automatically.